# How to fix error The process cannot access the file 'D:\myfolder\myproject\ExcelFolder\myFile.xlsx' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I tried to Upload my exel file it gives error.

**CODE**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection form) 
{       
    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExcelTemplates/" + file.FileName));
}
```

Comment: Is it being used by another process?? Do you have it open in Excel?

Comment: no it is not open in excel and in any other application

Comment: Check if your process run yet, it can lock your file.

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `Server.MapPath("~/ExcelTemplates/" + file.FileName)`? (please check in the `Immediate Window`)

Comment: `no it is not open in excel and in any other application` Your comment to the below answer shows this is not true - please remove this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file with a new name, may be it is still handled by the browser if you have tried to upload before.

btw it is recommended to rename uploaded files and use the file name only for display purpose, see the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

additionally you may see this [file upload sample](https://github.com/LazZiya/FileUpload) on GitHub using dropzone

Answer (score 1):

> Kill EXCEL.exe process from task manager. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Welcome friend. Glad to hear it.